# How do I produce a table of greening/browning trends for polygons I drew on my map?

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, evi, forest-ecology

I managed to create a Sen's slope map layer for my whole study area for Greening/Browning trends across a national park (I added a map of this below) but I am struggling to pull out greening/browning trends for specific polygons
I need the data for these GPS coordinates (250m size polygons around these points)
How can  I do this? I am very new to Earth Engine.

```
ID  Latitude    Longitude

1   48.83955    13.88756

2   49.0636     13.50614

3   48.8052     13.86793

4   49.05351    13.44312

5   48.83311    13.85478

6   49.13438    13.33609

7   49.15664    13.27783

8   48.83342    13.91959

9   48.89841    13.78828

// Get MODIS 250m vegetation data.
var mod13 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1');

// Get features of the forest national parks.
var nps = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/202006/polygons')
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('NAME', ['Šumava']));
  
  // Filter MODIS images to summer months between Jan and Apr 2000-2019,
// Add observation year as an image property.
var mod13Summer = mod13.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 4, 'month'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2000, 2019, 'year'))
  .map(function(img) {
    return img.set('year', img.date().get('year'));
  });

// Generate lists of images from the year using a join.
var mod13SummerAnnualJoin = ee.Join.saveAll('same_year').apply({
  primary: mod13Summer.distinct('year'),
  secondary: mod13Summer,
  condition: ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'year', rightField: 'year'})
});

// Calculate annual max EVI composite images from the "same year" join lists.
// Return an image with two bands for use in time series slope calculation;
// year as band 1, max EVI as band 2.
var summerStats = ee.ImageCollection(mod13SummerAnnualJoin.map(function(img) {
  var year = img.get('year');
  var yearCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(img.get('same_year'));
  var max = yearCol.select('EVI').max();
  var yr = ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(year)).toShort();
  return ee.Image.cat(yr, max).rename(['year', 'max']).set('year', year);
}));


// Calculate time series slope using sensSlope().
var sens = summerStats.reduce(ee.Reducer.sensSlope());

// Define a function to calculate a histogram of slope values to be calculated
// for each park; defining a custom histogram function instead of using
// ui.Chart.image.histogram because it does not allow baseline to be set as 0,
// which is important when evaluating positive and negative slope frequency.
function getHistogram(sensImg, geometry, title) {
  // Calculate histogram as an ee.Array table.
  var hist = sensImg.select('slope').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.autoHistogram(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 250,
    maxPixels: 1e13,
  });

  // Get the array and extract the bin column and pixel count columns.
  var histArray = ee.Array(hist.get('slope'));
  var binBottom = histArray.slice(1, 0, 1);
  var nPixels = histArray.slice(1, 1, null);

  // Chart the two arrays using the `ui.Chart.array.values` function.
  var histColumnFromArray =
    ui.Chart.array.values({array: nPixels, axis: 0, xLabels: binBottom})
      .setChartType('LineChart')
      .setOptions({
        title: title + ' forest condition trend histogram',
        hAxis: {title: 'Slope'},
        vAxis: {title: 'Pixel count'},
        pointSize: 0,
        lineSize: 2,
        colors: ['1b7837'],
        legend: {position: 'none'}
      });

  return histColumnFromArray;
}

// Get the slope histogram charts and print them to the console per park.
print(getHistogram(
  sens, nps.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Šumava')), 'Šumava'));
print(getHistogram(
  sens, nps.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Šumava')),
  'Šumava'));
  
// Infer pixel-wise vegetation condition based on sign of the slope.
var cond = ee.Image.cat(sens.select('slope').gt(0).rename('greening'),
                        sens.select('slope').lt(0).rename('browning'));

// Calculate area under greening and browning in each national park.
var npsRes = cond.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
                 .reduceRegions(nps, ee.Reducer.sum(), 250);
  
  
// Format results of the greening and browning for use in a table; convert sq m
// to sq km and calculate fraction of each; add as feature properties.
npsRes = npsRes.map(function(feature) {
  var browningSqM = feature.getNumber('browning');
  var greeningSqM = feature.getNumber('greening');
  var forestSqM = feature.area();
  return feature.set({
    'Browning sq km': browningSqM.divide(1e6),
    'Browning fraction': browningSqM.divide(forestSqM),
    'Greening sq km': greeningSqM.divide(1e6),
    'Greening fraction': greeningSqM.divide(forestSqM),
  });
});

// Display area summary of vegetation condition as a table "chart".
print(ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(npsRes.select(['NAME', 'Browning sq km',
    'Browning fraction', 'Greening sq km', 'Greening fraction']),
    'NAME')
  .setChartType('Table'));
  
  
// Prepare to display vegetation condition to the map; set map display options.
Map.setOptions('SATELLITE');
Map.centerObject(nps, 10);

// Set visualisation parameters for greening and browning areas; display to map.
var visParams = {
  opacity: 1,
  bands: ['slope'],
  min: -55,
  max: 55,
  palette:
    ['8c510a', 'd8b365', 'f6e8c3', 'f5f5f5', 'd9f0d3', '7fbf7b', '1b7837']
};
Map.addLayer(sens.clipToCollection(nps), visParams, 'Sen\'s slope');

// Draw national park boundaries to the map.
var paimg = ee.Image().byte().paint(nps, 0, 2);
Map.addLayer(paimg, {palette: '000000'}, 'National Parks');[enter image description here][2]
```

[[image: Image of Sen's slope of greening/browning trends across the national park for the whole study area][2]]

[[image: graph I need to create for each of the pixels I drew on the maptable I need to make but for the separate pixels]

[image: Table of Greening/Browning stats]